# "This in itself (already) shows the naturality of such approach". Should I remove "already"?

Tags: grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

I want to say and emphasis that the situation from the previous sentence already shows the naturality of some approach. I want to write:

> This in itself (**already**) shows the naturality of such approach.

However, I am not sure if I can use the word "**already**". Is "**This in itself already**" grammatically correct?

Comment: In what way does adding the word "already" change what you want to convey with this sentence?

Comment: @JeremyC I think it puts additial emphasis which I want actually. I am worried if it is correct though.

Comment: Use of the adverb there is unexceptionable. It's a matter of style and emphasis.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the grammar. With "already" included, I, as a reader would expect you to go on with some additional point or points that support the idea that the approach is natural.

Comment: @JeremyC Which I didn't give... Thanks for this hint. Maybe I will add one more sentence.

Comment: "naturalness" is more natural than "naturality".

Comment: Yes, naturality is not a word, really. I suggest: **shows that such an approach is natural or is a natural one**. English does not much like abstract nouns in contexts like these, unlike Spanish or French, for example. I have to say that your use of **already** and the abstract noun makes me think of a Romance language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic sentence would be:

> This shows the naturality of such approach.

If you want to add some emphasis, you add "in itself":

> This **in itself** shows the naturality of such approach.

And for even more emphasis:

> This **in itself already** shows the naturality of such approach.

Therefore, even if it is not needed for the proper understanding of the sentence, it adds to the style.

---

If we make a short analysis of the sentence, we discover that:

- "in itself" adds emphasis to "this";
- "already" adds emphasis to "shows".

Answer (score 0):

I agree that there is nothing wrong grammatically with any of

> This shows
>
> This already shows
>
> This itself shows
>
> This itself already shows
>
> This in(by) itself shows
>
> This in(by) itself already shows

It is a matter of style which to use. Personally, I find the "This by itself shows" to be a concise and clear way to emphasize that whatever "this" refers to is a sufficient demonstration although there is additional evidence.

But both "naturality," a word I have never seen used, and "naturalness," a word that seems far from euphonious, bother my sense of style far more than combining "in itself" and "already." Personally, I'd write

> This by itself shows the approach to be natural.